# Unable to add themes in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, themes

I've downloaded, unpacked, and copied to /usr/share/themes two themes from gnome-look.org, but they're not showing up in GNOME Tweaks.  Anybody have any suggestions?  I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: @Ken Did you try restarting Tweak tool? What if you copy the theme folder in `~/.themes`? Can you please share links of the themes?

Comment: @Nmath *GNOME3 does not officially support themes*: I am using themes on GNOME 3.36.4 after downloading from GNOME-look and copying in `~./themes`. :)

Comment: @Kulfy, the links are here:

https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1014311/ and
https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1006793

I tried restarting the Tweak tool, and I tried restarting the computer, but no joy.  I originally installed the two parts to the hidden themes directory in /home/kwright, but moved them to /usr/share/themes when they didn't work.

Comment: @KenWright both themes seem from 2008... way before gnome3. They may be not supported by it.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity, I'll bet you're right.  I'll have to see if I can find a similar theme supported by Gnome 3.

Comment: See if they are GTK 3.